# Android: Control with own parameters

Tags: android, parameters, controls, custom-controls

I want to ask you, if is possible in Android to make a control, which will take my own parameters.
I want, that my control will looks like:

```
<my.own.control
    android:style
    attributes
>
    <include name=”” value=””>
    <include name=”” value=””>
</my.own.control>
```

or

```
<my.own.control
    Android:style
    attributes
>
    <include>
        <name></name>
        <value></value>
    </include>
    <include>
        <name></name>
        <value></value>
    </include>
</my.own.control>
```

The reason why I want to do it this way, is to dynamically edit includes.
The most important question is, how to read includes on initialize.

Or do you have another advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible.
There is an open bug on the android project for it that was reviewed and accepted by Romain-gui, one of the lead android developers at google.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14532
There is however a workaround, it is explained very well at http://kevindion.com/2011/01/custom-xml-attributes-for-android-widgets/